# Concatenar n caracteres de uma palavra digitada

Tags: c, string, concatenação-de-string

Quero fazer um programa na qual o usuário digite uma palavra qualquer e fique armazenada em um string, logo após é necessário armazenar essa mesma palavra em outra string só que na forma inversa, por exemplo se foi digitado "BRASIL" quero que retorne "LISARB". Consegui inverter as posições dos caracteres, no entanto não consigo concatenar os caracteres para que os mesmos sejam exibidos em uma linha só.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
char p[100], c, invertida;
int tam ,i;

printf ("\n Digite uma palavra: ");
gets (p);
tam = strlen(p);

for (i=tam -1 ; i>=0; i--)
{
    c = p[i];
    strcat (c,p[i]);
}
printf("\n %s", c);
}
```

Comment: Essa linha, `p[i] = p[i]`, não parece muito certa ou fazer sentido. Poderia rever o código que postou na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um método simples de você fazer isso é assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char p[100], c, invertida[100];
    int tam, i;

    printf ("\n Digite uma palavra: ");
    gets (p);
    tam = strlen(p);

    int count = 0;
    for (i=tam -1 ; i>=0; i--)
    {
        invertida[count] = p[i];
        count += 1;
    }
    // Finaliza String
    invertida[count] = '\0';
    printf("\n %s", invertida);
}
```

Enquanto percorre a string ao contrario você soma um contador para colocar o valor na string invertida.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user uma função em C responsável por inverter os caracteres, chamada `strrev()`.

[strrev](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strrev-function-in-c/)

```
char *strrev(char *str);
```